# please help me solve the question which proving X[N-k] is the complex conjugate of X[k]

Tags: dft, complex, conjugate

Show for the DFT that if all x[n] are real, then X[N - k] is the complex conjugate of X[k] for k > 0. (i.e. if
X[k] is a + bi, then X[N - k] is a - bi)